# Azure App Service getting Error 404 when redirected via NGINX

Tags: azure, nginx, azure-web-app-service

1. I created a VM, port 80 is open and installed NGINX on it.
2. I created 2 App Services which can be accessed via x1.azurewebsites.net and x2.azurewebsites.net

I configured the VM to act as an load balancer but when redirecting the traffic I get the following: https://i.gyazo.com/b94bed9c90d3b0f0c400c83f762f0544.png

I am not using my own domain. Does someone know what the issue could be?

I got the following configurations:

```
upstream backend {
  server xx.azurewebsites.net;
  server xxx.azurewebsites.net;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /var/www/html;

  server_name_;

  location / {
   proxy_pass http://backend;
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Azure App Service uses cookies for ARR (Application Request Routing). You have to make sure that your NGinx reverse proxy configuration pass the correct cookie / header to your web app.

The other possibility (to make sure the behavior comes from ARR) is to disable it: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/disabling-arrs-instance-affinity-in-windows-azure-web-sites/

Comment: How can I make sure that it passes correct cookie/header if there are multiple servers defined in nginx?

Comment: Can you past your nginx configuration, please ? (the server section where you set the proxy to your web apps)

Comment: Added the configurations to the main post.

Comment: I think you need to configure the proxy to pass headers and update cookie domain. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass_request_headers and http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_domain